# Why do we write wave function for electronic transition in molecules like this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, molecules

Why do we write transition between two different electronic states like that:
$$\bar p_{if}=\langle \psi_i|\bar p|\psi_f \rangle$$
And not like that:
$$\bar p_{if}=\langle \psi_f|\bar p|\psi_i \rangle$$
where $i$ and $f$ mean initial and final states.
As I understand, we want to see how much those states overlap each other, but why are we using operator on final state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two numbers are complex conjugate of each other - thus, whatever is the calculation, they are manipulated to give something real. E.g., in the at lowest order we simply use the Fermi Golden rule
$$w_{i\rightarrow f} \propto |\langle \psi_i|\bar{p}|\psi_f\rangle|^2=
\langle \psi_i|\bar{p}|\psi_f\rangle\langle \psi_i|\bar{p}|\psi_f\rangle^*=
\langle \psi_i|\bar{p}|\psi_f\rangle\langle \psi_f|\bar{p}|\psi_i\rangle.$$

Comment: Okay, but according to fermi rule we should use operator on initial state

Comment: @cover the question is about the order of indices: it si convenient to have them written in the same order as in the bra and ket. Some field prefer to multiply operators in the other direction - it doesn't make difference, as long as it does not change the result.